# Node.js Working with Multiple Tier SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, asynchronous

I'm busy reworking an old program with Node.js and I'm having some difficulty with the code not executing synchronously.

The PostgreSQL table structure is along the lines of

```
create table tier01 (
    t01_idno integer,
    t01_desc char(10)
);
insert into tier01 values
(1, 'Tier 01 A'),
(2, 'Tier 01 B');

create table tier02 (
    t02_t01_idno integer,
    t02_idno integer,
    t02_desc char(10)
);
insert into tier02 values
(1, 1, 'Tier 02 A'),
(1, 2, 'Tier 02 B'),
(2, 1, 'Tier 02 A');

create table tier03 (
    t03_t02_idno integer,
    t03_idno integer,
    t03_desc char(10)
);
insert into tier03 values
(1, 1, 'Tier 02 A'),
(1, 2, 'Tier 02 B'),
(2, 1, 'Tier 02 A');
```

What I am trying to represent is essentially

```
select t01_desc, t02_desc, t03_desc
from tier01, tier02, tier03
where t01_idno = t02_t01_idno
and t02_idno = t03_t02_idno
```

But instead of the results appearing as

```
'Tier 01 A ','Tier 02 A ','Tier 03 A '
'Tier 01 A ','Tier 02 A ','Tier 03 B '
'Tier 01 A ','Tier 02 B ','Tier 03 A '
'Tier 01 B ','Tier 02 A ','Tier 03 A '
'Tier 01 B ','Tier 02 A ','Tier 03 B '
```

I'm trying to get

```
'Tier 01 A'
- - - 'Tier 02 A'
- - - - - - 'Tier 03 A'
- - - - - - 'Tier 03 B'
- - - 'Tier 02 B'
- - - - - - 'Tier 03 A'
'Tier 01 B'
- - - 'Tier 02 A'
- - - - - - 'Tier 03 A'
- - - - - - 'Tier 03 B'
```

Which I was able to do with PHP without any issues

```
////
// SQL
////

$lv_sql = " select * from tier01 " .
          " order by t01_idno ";
pg_prepare($lv_db, "tier01_cur", $lv_sql);

$lv_sql = " select * from tier02 " .
          " where t02_t01_idno = $1 " .
          " order by t02_idno ";
pg_prepare($lv_db, "tier02_cur", $lv_sql);

$lv_sql = " select * from tier03 " .
          " where t03_t02_idno = $1 " .
          " order by t03_idno ";
pg_prepare($lv_db, "tier03_cur", $lv_sql);

////
// Run
////

// LOOP THROUGH TIER01
$tier01_cur_query = pg_execute($lv_db, "tier01_cur", array());
while($tier01_cur = pg_fetch_row($tier01_cur_query)) {

   echo '<p>' . $tier01_cur[1] . '</p>';

   // LOOP THROUGH TIER02
   $tier02_cur_query = pg_execute($lv_db, "tier02_cur", array($tier01_cur[0]));
   while($tier02_cur = pg_fetch_row($tier02_cur_query)) {

      echo '<p> - - - ' . $tier02_cur[2] . '</p>';

      // LOOP THROUGH TIER03
      $tier03_cur_query = pg_execute($lv_db, "tier03_cur", array($tier02_cur[1]));
      while($tier03_cur = pg_fetch_row($tier03_cur_query)) {

         echo '<p> - - - - - - ' . $tier03_cur[2] . '</p>';

      }

   }

}
```

But I am not able to reproduce the same results with Node.js because the queries are executing asynchronously. I think I got pretty close (or maybe not close at all) by using the async and pg module but the code seems messy and it's still wrong.

```
////
// SQL
////

lv_sql = " select * from tier01 " +
         " order by t01_idno ";
var tier01_cur = lv_sql;

lv_sql = " select * from tier02 " +
         " where t02_t01_idno = $1 " +
         " order by t02_idno ";
var tier02_cur = lv_sql;

lv_sql = " select * from tier03 " +
         " where t03_t02_idno = $1 " +
         " order by t03_idno ";
var tier03_cur = lv_sql;

////
// Run
////

gv_async.series ([
function(series) {

   ////
   // CONNECT TO DATABASE
   ////

   lv_pgsql = l_database.client();

   lv_pgsql.connect();

   series();

},

function(series) {

   // QUERY TIER01
   lv_pgsql.query(tier01_cur, [], function(err, res) {

      // LOOP THROUGH TIER01
      gv_async.forEachOf(res.rows, function(data, cnt, callbacktier01) {

         console.log(res.rows[cnt].t01_desc);

         // QUERY TIER02
         lv_pgsql.query(tier02_cur, [res.rows[cnt].t01_idno], function(err, res) {

            // LOOP THROUGH TIER02
            gv_async.forEachOf(res.rows, function(data, cnt, callbacktier02) {

               console.log(" - - - " + res.rows[cnt].t02_desc);

               // QUERY TIER03
               lv_pgsql.query(tier03_cur, [res.rows[cnt].t02_idno], function(err, res) {

                  // LOOP THROUGH TIER03
                  gv_async.forEachOf(res.rows, function(data, cnt, callbacktier03) {

                     console.log(" - - - - - - " + res.rows[cnt].t03_desc);
                     callbacktier03();

                  }, function(err, res) {
                     callbacktier02();
                  });

               });

            }, function(err, res) {
               callbacktier01();
            });

         });

      }, function(err, res) {
         series();
      });

   });

},
function(series) {

   ////
   // DISCONNECT DATABASE
   ////

   lv_pgsql.end();

   series();

   // BEING CALLED WITH AJAX SO
   // MUST SEND A RESPONSE
   res.send(null);

}
]);
```

The Node.js code is giving me the following output

```
Tier 01 A
Tier 01 B
 - - - Tier 02 A
 - - - Tier 02 B
 - - - Tier 02 A
 - - - - - - Tier 03 A
 - - - - - - Tier 03 B
 - - - - - - Tier 03 A
 - - - - - - Tier 03 A
 - - - - - - Tier 03 B
```

I'm having issues trying to recreate code intended for synchronous usage although I don't know the correct Node.js approach to program flow like this, any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've found the solution, it seems to work when done using the built in async and await (available from Node Version 7.6.0) instead of the npm async module.

This seems to be a lot neater and faster too which is just great.

```
f_retrievedata(function() {
   res.send(null);
});

async function f_retrievedata(callback) {

    var lv_sql = "";

    lv_sql = " select * from tier01 " +
             " order by t01_idno ";
    var tier01_cur = lv_sql;

    lv_sql = " select * from tier02 " +
             " where t02_t01_idno = $1 " +
             " order by t02_idno ";
    var tier02_cur = lv_sql;

    lv_sql = " select * from tier03 " +
             " where t03_t02_idno = $1 " +
             " order by t03_idno ";
    var tier03_cur = lv_sql;

    var lr_tier01 = "";
    var lr_tier02 = "";
    var lr_tier03 = "";

    lv_pgsql = l_database.client();
    await lv_pgsql.connect();

    // LOOP THROUGH TIER01
    lr_tier01 = await lv_pgsql.query(tier01_cur, []);
    lr_tier01 = await lr_tier01.rows;
    for(cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < lr_tier01.length; cnt1 ++) {

            console.log(lr_tier01[cnt1].t01_desc);

            // LOOP THROUGH TIER02
            lr_tier02 = await lv_pgsql.query(tier02_cur, [lr_tier01[cnt1].t01_idno]);
            lr_tier02 = await lr_tier02.rows;
            for(cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < lr_tier02.length; cnt2 ++) {

                    console.log( " - - - " + lr_tier02[cnt2].t02_desc);

                    // LOOP THROUGH TIER03
                    lr_tier03 = await lv_pgsql.query(tier03_cur, [lr_tier02[cnt2].t02_idno]);
                    lr_tier03 = await lr_tier03.rows;
                    for(cnt3 = 0; cnt3 < lr_tier03.length; cnt3 ++) {

                            console.log( " - - - - - - " + lr_tier03[cnt3].t03_desc);

                    }

            }

    }

    callback();

}
```